# When running a spring boot webapp in docker, should I use the "-server" java flag?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I was reading about escape analysis with java and the recommendation is to run java using the `-server` flag.  Is this a best practice when running a spring boot application in docker?

**UPDATE**
I'm currently using java 8 but hope to be on java 11 by the end of the year

Comment: No. How old is the article and what version of Java?

Comment: I updated with versions; can you elaborate why `-server` is not necessary?

Comment: Do you have problem with running it without `-server` option?  if yes then give more details about your spring boot application

Comment: I vote this question to be closed because I think most of questions on SO include a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it. or are about asking specific related concept but this one is not

Comment: @Null No.  This is about how to utilize a given JVM feature.  Perfectly well suited for here (but perhaps with a bit of rewording).

Comment: Please add link to the article in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your java version is 64-Bit then the `-server` is implicit (see [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html))

> -server
>
> Selects the Java HotSpot Server VM. The 64-bit version of the JDK supports only the Server VM, so in that case the option is
>   implicit.

The escape analysis is supported only by the Java HotSpot Server and it is enabled by default

> -XX:+DoEscapeAnalysis
>
> Enables the use of escape analysis. This option is enabled by default. To disable the use of escape analysis, specify
>   -XX:-DoEscapeAnalysis. Only the Java HotSpot Server VM supports this option.

If no option specified (either client or server) the Java launcher detects if it runs on a "server-class" machine according to [this table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html).

On a machine that it's not "server-class" (32-Bit) I would run Spring Boot with the `-server` option. The -`client` option is for GUIs.

Not sure if that answers your question but I hope it helps.